# how to measure performance of external website

Tags: javascript, navigation-timing-api

I want to measure the performance page load of an external website such as Facebook,youtube.. I found navigation timing as a tool to realize that. But the problem that it's done only with my website. Otherwise Can I exeucte navigation timing api when I open Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to measure performance of site is https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/.

If you want to measure XMLHttpRequest timing open Developer Tools in Chrome.

Comment: I want to use this API on my web application